# How exactly do I make a button start a database (sql) query in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

I'm trying to create a feedback page on this website I'm coding and I need my submit button to start a query so that the message is sent and stored in a feedback table in my database.

But I can't seem to be able to find the reason my implementation does not work. I think it worked this way the last time, any help would be appreciated.

```php
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="msgType">What is your concern?</label>
                            <select name="msgType" method="post" class="form-control input-lg" id="msgType">
                                <option value="1">I wish to report incorrect information cited on the website.</option>
                                <option value="2">I wish to report the existence of another bistro.</option>
                                <option value="3">I wish to thank the admin personally.</option>
                                <option value="4">I wish to express some other concern.</option>
                            </select>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message">Your message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" method="post" rows="15" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Thou, dear customer, may express Your concern here in any extent or form your majesty finds appropriate."></textarea>
                        </div> 
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted_feedback" value="1">
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
<!-- QUERY SECTION -->
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submitted_feedback']) == 1)
{
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['message']);

    $q = "INSERT INTO feedback(type, message) VALUES ($_POST[msgType], '$message')";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    echo 'dis is running';
    if($r)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your message was sent! :)');</script>";
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: it doesn't work because `isset($_POST['submitted_feedback'])` returns false

Comment: You don't have any `<form>` tags to submit anything.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons with the type submit, are intended to submit forms. Your markup doesn't have any `<form> </form>` tags at all.

[Here you go](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)